# provider duplicate while compiling a Cordova application for the Android platform

Tags: angularjs, cordova, duplicates, apk, android-manifest

I try to compile an Angular JS app with Cordova to get an apk.
I use this command :
***cordova build android***

I get this ERROR message :
(...)
***"Element provider#android.support.v4.content.FileProvider at AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-17:20 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-14:20"***
(...)

And in my AndroidManifest.xml i see 2 providers

```
<provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

<provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

---

I tried to delete one of the duplicate in my AndroidManifest.xml and do the same command again.
However i get the same error and the line is back in the file.

Tried other solutions on the site but it doesn't work.

Help please